# Getting custom email template name in system configuration

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, configuration, template, email-templates

I need to get custom email template in admin system configuration.

**system.xml**

> This is my email template field code.

```
<email_template>
    <label>Email Template</label>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
</email_template>
```

**config.xml**

```
<template>
    <email>
    <custom_email_template translate="label" module="eztestimonial">
    <label>Custom Email Template</label>
    <file>mymodule/custom_email.html</file>
    <type>html</type>
    </custom_email_template>
    </email>
</template>
<default>
    <mymodulesettings>
      <email>
          <email_template>custom_email_template</email_template>
      </email>
    </mymodulesettings>
</default>
```

And i have added email.html file in locale/en_US/template/email/mymodule/ path
Now i got a outut like this
[image]

But i need to show my custom email name in that dropdown.
like:[image]
I refer AW Blog Extension for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `config.xml` you should have your template declared inside the `global` tag and have a label on it.

```
<global>
...
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_email_template translate="label" module="eztestimonial">
                <label>Custom Email Template</label><!-- this should be shown in the config dropdown-->
                <file>mymodule/custom_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
...
</global>
```

Right now you have this outside the `global` tag.

**[EDIT]**
And in order to work, the path of your `system.xml` field must match the name of the template with `_` instead of `/`. In your case `custom_email_template`.

So your system.xml should look like this:

```
<sections>
    <custom ...>
       ....
       <groups>
           <email ....>
              ...
              <template>
                  <label>Email Template</label>
                  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                  <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
              </template>
           </email>
       </groups>
    </custom>
</sections>
```

And the `<default>` tag in `config.xml` should be

```
<default>
    <custom>
      <email>
          <template>custom_email_template</template>
      </email>
    </custom> 
</default>
```

Comment: i give that inside the global tag,but i cant get that email template label in system configuration.

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes,i clear the cache many time.I getting same response

Comment: I've edited the answer. Maybe that works.